# Formulating partial derivative in terms of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative, tensors

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients

I am using function `tensorflow.gradients`, which takes tensors $y$ and $x$ and returns the partial derivative with respect to $x$. In case of multiple $x$'s, it returns the sum of all partial derivatives $dy/dx$.

But, I have only a matrix $P$ of shape `(time_n, freq_n)`. Here, the first dimension is for temporal information, and the second dimension stores the frequency information. If I want to calculate the partial derivative $dP/dt$ (with respect to first dimension [time]), what will be my $y$ and $x$?

I think, $y = P$, but what will be $x$ and its dimension?

Comment: I guess the reader doesn't need to go through the doc, it's just for reference. I have clearly explained my input and what I'm looking for.

Comment: They are tensors or in simple words multi-dimensional arrays/matrices. My linear algebra is not extremely good, what I'm looking for is the matrix representation of the partial derivative of a matrix with respect to its first dimension.

Comment: Let's say, you define partial derivative with matrices $dx/dy$ where both $x$ and $y$ are matrices. 
Now, I have only one matrix $x$ with shape (n_time, n_freq). I want to know what would be the appropriate $y$ so that I can find the $dx/dy$ which will give me the partial derivative of $x$ with respect to the first dimension. So, $y$ denotes the first dimension in matrix form.

Comment: Matrices or matrix-valued functions? The derivative of a (constant) matrix is zero. Boring.

Comment: yes, I guess I complete made a mistake by using the matrix analogy for the tensor. Thanks for the feedback. I think I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you mean is that you have an $n$-dimensional vector of times $t$ and a matrix $P$ such that $tP = \nu$ calculates an $n$-dimensional vector of frequencies $\nu$, and you would like to calculate the gradient of the function $f: t \mapsto tP$ with respect to $t$.

In this case, the gradient is just $P$ itself, and in general the derivative of a linear function is itself. If this is unfamiliar, check that $f_i = \sum t_jP_{ji}$ so that $\nabla f_i = (\dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial t_j})_i = (P_{ji})_j$. The gradient is then the list of all of these, $(\nabla f_i)_i = ((P_{ji})_j)_i = P$.

Comment: Note: I think your question is a bit unclear, and this answer may or may not be what you are looking for. Hoping this answer can at least help clarify your question :)

Comment: Yes, it's not the answer but I think I have figured it out. I am upvoting your answer for the feedback but I can't accept it as it's not the exact answer. I will check my intuition experimentally to see if I'm in the right direction or not. Thanks. I formulated it in a wrong way due to not having enough theoretical understanding of linear algebra.